# Annotate points in a stripplot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, annotate, stripplot

Is it possible to annotate each point in a `seaborn.stipplot`? My data is in `pandas`. I realize that annotate works for `matplotlib`, but I have not found it to work in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`seaborn` is a high-level API for `matplotlib`, so assign the returned `axes` to an alias, and then use the object with `.annotate`.

This example is adapted from the `seaborn` docs [here](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html).

**Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `pandas 2.0.0`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sat_mean = tips.loc[tips['day'] == 'Sat']['total_bill'].mean()

ax = sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)

ax.annotate("Saturday\nMean",
            xy=(2, sat_mean), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(.5, .5), textcoords='axes fraction',
            horizontalalignment="center",
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",
                            connectionstyle="arc3"),
            bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
            )

# ax.get_figure().savefig('tips_annotation.png')
```

[image]